# Django Admin searching for strange CSS

Tags: css, django, django-admin

I'm running django 1.5.1 with python 2.7. When I try to open the admin page, it cannot load the css because it's searching for files with names like 'base.c8269a10a4bc.css' (the css I'd normally expect with admin is accessible). Apart from this, the admin seems to be ok.

I'm also using pipeline and memcached if that helps.

Comment: maybe you can use collect static?

Comment: collect static would work - my solution was to copy base.css to base.c8269a10a4bc.css and so on. I just want to know why it would happen